# Point style with height, width and angle

Tags: qgis, style, fields-attributes, vector-layer

I'm searching for a special style for a point shape. In attribut table, I have, among others, 3 fields: height, width and angle.
I would like to use these 3 fields to represent my points as turned rectangles.

Somebody have an idea to do this ?

Comment: Try this approach [Rotate marker symbols individually in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216987/rotate-marker-symbols-individually-in-qgis/216994#216994).

Comment: Yeah but in that case u'll be playing with rotation only, not with height and width ... another solution would be to try geometry generator but it seems imposible to combine geometry generator with rotation ... unless u build your own function computing the vertices coordinates after the rotation ... it must be possible ...

Comment: i got the answer on an other forum. I have to use ellipse marker with a rectangular form. Height, width and angle can be inquired.

Comment: Pointing to this ressource would be nice !? How do u use ellipse "with a rectangular form" ?

Comment: Here is the ressource, it's french forum. Ellipse marker is a marker where you can chose height, width and angle. But you can chose form type : ellipse, rectangle, diamond, cross... http://www.forumsig.org/showthread.php/44259-Repr%C3%A9sentation-ponctuel-en-fonction-de-champs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the 'ellipse' theme that provides the height and width parameter, in addition to rotation and color (as suggested by Colas):

[image]

Comment: Yes that's it !