# Rotating marker symbols using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, markers

I imported a delimiter text layer in QGIS with 4 columns (`lon`,`lat`,`angle`,`norm`). My goal is to show these points with a specific symbol (an arrow), oriented accordidng to the `angle` field.

I think I found the right tool from another post: [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216987/rotate-marker-symbols-individually-in-qgis#:~:text=This%20is%20how%20it%20is,Symbology%20tab%20%3E%20Advanced%20%3E%20Rotation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216987/rotate-marker-symbols-individually-in-qgis#:%7E:text=This%20is%20how%20it%20is,Symbology%20tab%20%3E%20Advanced%20%3E%20Rotation).

However the symbol with the original orientation is kept (arrow pointing to the North).

Could someone help me understand how to get rid of this symbol?

[image]

EDIT :
[image]

Comment: From what you show only the rotated symbol should appear. Don't you have a duplicate of the  layer in your map?

Comment: I checked but it is not the case...

Comment: Then maybe there are duplicates in your data, same position, different angles ? Sait-on-jamais

Comment: Do you have multiple [symbol layers](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#moderate-fa-adding-symbol-layers)?

Comment: I suspect @Kasper's theory of *"same position, different angles"* is right. You can check by selecting one of your points (by dragging, rather than clicking) then look in the attribute table to see how many features are actually selected.

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! I tried to move one point and it was dragged away from the arrow pointing North, as if there were duplicates in my dataset indeed ! However, I don't understand why I have duplicates or how to solve this issue. I only have one shapefile layer with the four fields (X,Y,angle,norm) as mentionned before... (I added a screenshot to the original post)